# java.net.ProtocolException: Server redirected too many times (20) when publishing to Azure Devops

Tags: azure, sbt

I am attempting to publish an artifact to an Azure devops feed, self hosted. I have successfully published a normal maven project to the feed without issue. When i attempt to use sbt to publish a scala package I get this error.

```
[error] java.net.ProtocolException: Server redirected too many  times (20)
[error]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[error]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
[error]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
[error]         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
[error]         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
[error]         at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:2048)
[error]         at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:2043)
[error]         at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569)
[error]         at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:2042)
[error]         at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1609)
[error]         at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1589)
[error]         at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:224)
[error]         at org.apache.ivy.util.url.BasicURLHandler.upload(BasicURLHandler.java:288)
[error]         at org.apache.ivy.util.url.URLHandlerDispatcher.upload(URLHandlerDispatcher.java:82)
[error]         at org.apache.ivy.util.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:150)
[error]         at org.apache.ivy.plugins.repository.url.URLRepository.put(URLRepository.java:84)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.ConvertResolver$LocalIfFileRepo.put(ConvertResolver.scala:368)
[error]         at org.apache.ivy.plugins.repository.AbstractRepository.put(AbstractRepository.java:130)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.ConvertResolver$ChecksumFriendlyURLResolver.put(ConvertResolver.scala:118)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.ConvertResolver$ChecksumFriendlyURLResolver.put$(ConvertResolver.scala:105)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.ConvertResolver$$anonfun$defaultConvert$lzycompute$1$PluginCapableResolver$1.put(ConvertResolver.scala:165)
[error]         at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.RepositoryResolver.publish(RepositoryResolver.java:216)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.$anonfun$publish$5(IvyActions.scala:504)
[error]         at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
[error]         at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyUtil$.retryWithBackoff(IvyUtil.scala:22)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.$anonfun$publish$4(IvyActions.scala:503)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.$anonfun$publish$4$adapted(IvyActions.scala:501)
[error]         at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
[error]         at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
[error]         at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1431)
[error]         at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:74)
[error]         at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:73)
[error]         at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:56)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.publish(IvyActions.scala:501)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.$anonfun$publish$3(IvyActions.scala:143)
[error]         at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.withChecksums(IvyActions.scala:157)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.withChecksums(IvyActions.scala:150)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.$anonfun$publish$1(IvyActions.scala:143)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.$anonfun$publish$1$adapted(IvyActions.scala:133)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$Module.$anonfun$withModule$1(Ivy.scala:245)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.$anonfun$withIvy$1(Ivy.scala:209)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.sbt$internal$librarymanagement$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:72)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$$anon$1.call(Ivy.scala:82)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:113)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:91)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.$anonfun$withFileLock$1(Locks.scala:119)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:12)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withFileLock(Locks.scala:119)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:71)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:59)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:47)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:36)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:82)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:203)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:200)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:244)


[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.publish(IvyActions.scala:133)
[error]         at sbt.Classpaths$.$anonfun$publishTask$4(Defaults.scala:3553)
[error]         at sbt.Classpaths$.$anonfun$publishTask$4$adapted(Defaults.scala:3546)
[error]         at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:49)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:62)
[error]         at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(Transform.scala:68)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:282)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:23)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:291)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:282)
[error]         at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:265)
[error]         at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:64)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
[error]         at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
[error] Caused by: java.net.ProtocolException: Server redirected too many  times (20)
[error]         at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:2005)
[error]         at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1589)
[error]         at java.base/java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:529)
[error]         at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:308)
[error]         at org.apache.ivy.util.url.BasicURLHandler.upload(BasicURLHandler.java:284)
[error]         at org.apache.ivy.util.url.URLHandlerDispatcher.upload(URLHandlerDispatcher.java:82)
[error]         at org.apache.ivy.util.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:150)
[error]         at org.apache.ivy.plugins.repository.url.URLRepository.put(URLRepository.java:84)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.ConvertResolver$LocalIfFileRepo.put(ConvertResolver.scala:368)
[error]         at org.apache.ivy.plugins.repository.AbstractRepository.put(AbstractRepository.java:130)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.ConvertResolver$ChecksumFriendlyURLResolver.put(ConvertResolver.scala:118)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.ConvertResolver$ChecksumFriendlyURLResolver.put$(ConvertResolver.scala:105)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.ConvertResolver$$anonfun$defaultConvert$lzycompute$1$PluginCapableResolver$1.put(ConvertResolver.scala:165)
[error]         at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.RepositoryResolver.publish(RepositoryResolver.java:216)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.$anonfun$publish$5(IvyActions.scala:504)
[error]         at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
[error]         at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyUtil$.retryWithBackoff(IvyUtil.scala:22)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.$anonfun$publish$4(IvyActions.scala:503)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.$anonfun$publish$4$adapted(IvyActions.scala:501)
[error]         at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
[error]         at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
[error]         at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1431)
[error]         at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:74)
[error]         at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:73)
[error]         at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:56)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.publish(IvyActions.scala:501)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.$anonfun$publish$3(IvyActions.scala:143)
[error]         at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.withChecksums(IvyActions.scala:157)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.withChecksums(IvyActions.scala:150)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.$anonfun$publish$1(IvyActions.scala:143)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.$anonfun$publish$1$adapted(IvyActions.scala:133)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$Module.$anonfun$withModule$1(Ivy.scala:245)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.$anonfun$withIvy$1(Ivy.scala:209)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.sbt$internal$librarymanagement$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:72)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$$anon$1.call(Ivy.scala:82)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:113)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:91)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.$anonfun$withFileLock$1(Locks.scala:119)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:12)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withFileLock(Locks.scala:119)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:71)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:59)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:47)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:36)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:82)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:203)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:200)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:244)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.publish(IvyActions.scala:133)
[error]         at sbt.Classpaths$.$anonfun$publishTask$4(Defaults.scala:3553)
[error]         at sbt.Classpaths$.$anonfun$publishTask$4$adapted(Defaults.scala:3546)
[error]         at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:49)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:62)
[error]         at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(Transform.scala:68)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:282)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:23)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:291)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:282)
[error]         at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:265)
[error]         at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:64)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
[error]         at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
[error] (publish) java.net.ProtocolException: Server redirected too many  times (20)
```

build.sbt

```
ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.13.10"
ThisBuild / versionScheme := Some("early-semver")

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "untitled",
    publishMavenStyle := true,
    publishTo := Some("XXX" at "https://XXX/XXX/_packaging/tsmaven/maven/v1"),
    credentials += Credentials (Path.userHome / ".sbt" / "azureArtifactsFeed.credentials") 
)
```

azureArtifactsFeed.credentials

```
realm=
host=XXX
user=[USERNAME]
password=[TOKEN]
```

Any help is appreciated.

sbt publish

expected a publish to maven feed

got error